# Database connection errors with docker-compose POSTGRES & SEQUELIZE

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

I have a node app that uses postgres and sequelize. I have a docker file that will run my server. I also have a docker compose file that will run a web image and db image that link my docker images and connect them together.

I am able to get my server running thorugh the docker file. I am trying to use the docker-compose file to run the database with it and and get them to work. I am getting a connection error with the database that is trying to connect and I am not sure where this error is coming from...

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD npm start
EXPOSE 5585
```

dock compose file:

```
version: "2"
services: 
  web:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - 80:5585
    command: npm start 
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@db:5432/addidas
  db:
    image: postgres 
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_USER=username
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=addidas
```

I am also using sequelize to connect my database with express. Do i need to change anythign to do that.

ERROR:

```
web_1  | Fri, 09 Nov 2018 18:26:47 GMT sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators at node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:242:13
web_1  | server is running at http://localhost:3001
web_1  | { SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.3:5432
web_1  |     at connection.connect.err (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:116:24)
web_1  |     at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:140:14)
web_1  |     at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
web_1  |     at Socket.reportStreamError (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:71:10)
web_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
web_1  |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
web_1  |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
web_1  |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
web_1  |   name: 'SequelizeConnectionRefusedError',
web_1  |   parent:
web_1  |    { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.3:5432
web_1  |        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1113:14)
web_1  |      errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1  |      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1  |      syscall: 'connect',
web_1  |      address: '172.19.0.3',
web_1  |      port: 5432 },
web_1  |   original:
web_1  |    { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.3:5432
web_1  |        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1113:14)
web_1  |      errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1  |      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1  |      syscall: 'connect',
web_1  |      address: '172.19.0.3',
web_1  |      port: 5432 } }
web_1  | { SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.3:5432
web_1  |     at connection.connect.err (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:116:24)
web_1  |     at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:140:14)
web_1  |     at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
web_1  |     at Socket.reportStreamError (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:71:10)
web_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
web_1  |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
web_1  |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
web_1  |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
web_1  |   name: 'SequelizeConnectionRefusedError',
web_1  |   parent:
web_1  |    { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.3:5432
web_1  |        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1113:14)
web_1  |      errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1  |      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1  |      syscall: 'connect',
web_1  |      address: '172.19.0.3',
web_1  |      port: 5432 },
web_1  |   original:
web_1  |    { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.3:5432
web_1  |        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1113:14)
web_1  |      errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1  |      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1  |      syscall: 'connect',
web_1  |      address: '172.19.0.3',
web_1  |      port: 5432 } }
```

Comment: Man can I hv your comment ?

Answer (score 1):

1st change to 5432 to defalut postgres port

```
db:
image: postgres 
restart: always
ports:
  - "5432:3306" //default postgres port 
environment: 
  - POSTGRES_USER=username
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
  - POSTGRES_DB=addidas
```

2. **Allow the port** you want to connect

`sudo ufw allow 5432`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
...
web:
    build: 
      context: .
    ports: 
      - 80:5585
    command: npm start
    network_mode: service:db 
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@db:5432/addidas
...
```

Another thing is that from the expose line I guess that you want to run the node app on port 5585. But it is actually running on port 3001 (Based on the 2. line of the error message)

Comment: can you post the connection code from the nodejs app?